# Apply fadeout effect to video at multiple places

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fadeout

I have a video of 12 seconds, frame rate is 30 frames per second.

I want to apply fade out effect to video on multiple places, for example from second 3rd to 4th and from second 7th to 8th.

Have a look at this command.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -strict experimental -vf fade=type=out:start_frame=91:nb_frames=29  -y final_out.mp4
```

Above command adds fade out effect from 3rd to 4th second properly, Now I have fired following command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -strict experimental -vf fade=type=out:start_frame=91:nb_frames=29 fade=type=out:start_frame=211:nb_frames=29 -y final_out.mp4
and
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -strict experimental -vf fade=type=out:start_frame=91:nb_frames=29 -y final_out.mp4 fade=type=out:start_frame=211:nb_frames=29
```

None of them are working, throwing following exception

```
[NULL @ 0x2dc83a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fade=type=out:start_frame=211:nb_frames=29'
fade=type=out:start_frame=211:nb_frames=29: Invalid argument
```

I was following [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#fade) documentation.

Is there any way to apply fade out effect on multiple time slices ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I think a link to the output would be more appropriate. When trying to understand the big picture of a question I dont want to see a giant code dump right away.

Comment: @StevenPenny What if the link goes away? I prefer this information to be available in the post.